# How to join two JDBC tables and avoid Exchange?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got ETL-like scenario, in which I read data from multiple JDBC tables and files and perform some aggregations and join between sources.

In one step I must join two JDBC tables. I've tried to do something like:

```scala
val df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("url", Database.DB_URL)
            .option("user", Database.DB_USER)
            .option("password", Database.DB_PASSWORD)
            .option("dbtable", tableName)
            .option("driver", Database.DB_DRIVER)
            .option("upperBound", data.upperBound)
            .option("lowerBound", data.lowerBound)
            .option("numPartitions", data.numPartitions)
            .option("partitionColumn", data.partitionColumn)
            .load();

val df2 = spark.read.format("jdbc")
            .option("url", Database.DB_URL)
            .option("user", Database.DB_USER)
            .option("password", Database.DB_PASSWORD)
            .option("dbtable", tableName)
            .option("driver", Database.DB_DRIVER)
            .option("upperBound", data2.upperBound)
            .option("lowerBound", data2.lowerBound)
            .option("numPartitions", data2.numPartitions)
            .option("partitionColumn", data2.partitionColumn)
            .load();

df1.join(df2, Seq("partition_key", "id")).show();
```

Note that `partitionColumn` in both cases is the same - "partition_key".

However, when I run such query, I can see unnecessary exchange (plan cleared for readability):

```scala
df1.join(df2, Seq("partition_key", "id")).explain(extended = true);
```

```
Project [many many fields]
+- Project [partition_key#10090L, iv_id#10091L, last_update_timestamp#10114,  ... more fields]
    +- SortMergeJoin [partition_key#10090L, id#10091L], [partition_key#10172L, id#10179L], Inner
       :- *Sort [partition_key#10090L ASC NULLS FIRST, iv_id#10091L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
       :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(partition_key#10090L, iv_id#10091L, 4)
       :     +- *Scan JDBCRelation((select mod(s.id, 23) as partition_key, s.* from tab2 s)) [numPartitions=23] [partition_key#10090L,id#10091L,last_update_timestamp#10114] PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(PARTITION_KEY)], ReadSchema: struct<partition_key:bigint,id:bigint,last_update_timestamp:timestamp>
       +- *Sort [partition_key#10172L ASC NULLS FIRST, id#10179L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
          +- Exchange hashpartitioning(partition_key#10172L, iv_id#10179L, 4)
             +- *Project [partition_key#10172L, id#10179L ... 75 more fields]
               +- *Scan JDBCRelation((select mod(s.id, 23) as partition_key, s.* from tab1 s)) [numPartitions=23] [fields] PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(ID), *IsNotNull(PARTITION_KEY)], ReadSchema: struct<partition_key:bigint,id:bigint...
```

If we have already partitioned reading with `numPartitions` and other options, partition count is the same, why there is a need for another Exchange? Can we somehow avoid this unnecessary shuffle? On the test data I see Sparks sends more than 150M of data during this Exchange, where production `Datasets` are much bigger, so it can be serious bottleneck.

Comment: `SortMergeJoin` suggests the datasets are huge. How many records? The key is the same, but how do you know the partitions and the keys are on the same machines? Is this predictable without your own custom Partitioner that is somehow stateful and shared between queries? Thinking aloud.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski On test dataset it's ~5 millions in one table and ~1,5 millions on the second table. Both of them are read with the same partitionColumn, so they should be one the same node - however it's RangePartitioned, not HashPartitioned, maybe that is the difference

Comment: _"so they should be one the same node"_ <-- how do you know that? IMHO partitions are not bound to executors deterministically. You could have partition 1 on executor 2 in one query and partition 1 on executor 1 in another. I think it's legit.

Comment: _"however it's RangePartitioned"_ <-- I don't get it? It's `hashpartitioning` so HashPartitioned, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe my understanding is wrong, but right after reading I have some partitioning, so HashPartitioning should give the same guarantees like RangePartitioning done by JDBCRelation. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski JdbcRelation uses RangePartitioning on reading. My initial thought, that this implementation just needs HashPartitioning instead of RangePartitioning

Comment: @user6910411 Can you please write an answer? Also, I join with two colimns, so it won't work now: https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-18067

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current implementation of the Date Source API there is no partitioning information passed upstream so even if data could be joined without a shuffle, Spark cannot use this information. Therefore your assumption that:

> JdbcRelation uses RangePartitioning on reading

is just incorrect. Furthermore it looks like Spark uses the same internal code to handle range-based JDBC partitions and predicate-based JDBC partitions. While the former one could be translated to `SortOrder`, the latter one might be incompatible with Spark SQL in general.

When in doubt, it is possible to retrieve `Partitioner` information using `QueryExecution` and internal `RDD`:

```
df.queryExecution.toRdd.partitioner
```

This might change in the future ([SPIP:​ ​ Data​ ​ Source​ ​ API​ ​ V2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12882332/SPIP%20Data%20Source%20API%20V2.pdf), [SPARK-15689 - Data source API v2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15689) and 
[Spark Data Frame. PreSorded partitions](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Spark-Data-Frame-PreSorded-partitions-tp22957.html) ).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski `outputPartitioning` is set when you shuffle the data and get `ShuffledRowRDD`. But I think you misunderstood me - when I said "partition specification" I meant `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, `numPartitions` used to prepare statements.

Comment: I don't see the difference between `outputPartitioning` and `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, `numPartitions` used to prepare statements. They are correlated in my opinion, i.e. you create JDBC partitions with the latter while   `outputPartitioning` preserves or modifies them when needed.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski If you take into account that `jdbc` source (same as other data sources) returns `Dataset` with `UnknownPartitioning` I am not sure where you see the correlation. Yes, theoretically this information could be passed downstream. It is not and in practice it is not easy to implement in general case (sorting integers is of course trivial). If you're trying to make some point I am keep missing I would sincerely appreciate  something more explicit :)