# Should Spark JDBC partitionColumns be recognized as DataFrame partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I've used `partitionColumn` options to read a 300 million row table, hoping to achieve low memory/disk requirements for my ETL job (in Spark 3.0.1).

However, the explain plan shows at the start/leaf:

```
+- Exchange hashpartitioning[partitionCol#1, 200), true, [id=#201]
   +- *(1) Scan JDBCRelation(table)[numPartitions=200] (partitionCol#1, time#2)...
```

I would have expected that shuffling was not necessary here, since the `partitionCol` was specified in the JDBC option.

There's a whole lot going on in the full plan, but every window operation partitions by `partitionCol` first and then other columns.

I've tried:

- Ensuring my columns are declared not-null (since I saw `Sort[partitionCol#1 ASC NULLS FIRST...]` being injected and thought that might be an issue)
- Checking dataframe partitioning: `jdbcDF.rdd.partitioner` is `None` (which seems to confirm it's not understood)

[How to join two JDBC tables and avoid Exchange?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660873/37193) leads to the [Datasource v2 partitioning reporting interface](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22389) (fixed in 2.3.1), but perhaps that doesn't extend to jdbc loading?